# How to enable xdebug in php:7.4-fpm-alpine docker container?

Tags: php, laravel, docker, xdebug, fpm

My target is to use this git repo for Laravel with xdebug for php-fpm:
https://github.com/aschmelyun/docker-compose-laravel

**When using this repo i run:**

1. docker-compose up -d --build site
2. docker-compose up

**Here is the docker file from above repo:**

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

ADD ./php/www.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
RUN addgroup -g 1000 laravel && adduser -G laravel -g laravel -s /bin/sh -D laravel
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html
RUN chown laravel:laravel /var/www/html
WORKDIR /var/www/html
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

**I have also added the port here (compose.dockerfile):**

```
php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
     # Added next line:
      - "9001:9001"                     
    networks:
      - laravel
```

**I have tried add this to the end of php.dockerfile:**

```
# Install essential build tools
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    git \
    yarn \
    autoconf \
    g++ \
    make \
    openssl-dev

# Install xdebug
RUN docker-php-source extract \
    && pecl install xdebug \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_enable=on\n" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=on\n" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_port=9001\n" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp\n" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=1\n" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    && docker-php-source delete \
    && rm -rf /tmp/*
```

This is the error I get when adding the above lines(It seems unrelated, but I guess it break some dependency):

```
mysql       | Version: '5.7.29'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
composer    | list [--xml] [--raw] [--format FORMAT] [--] [<namespace>]
composer    |
npm exited with code 1
composer exited with code
```

I have tried other things I found on google. However not been able to get it to work(since I really don´t understand what I do). I think the above feelt like it was the closed I got, but maybe I'm completly wrong.

I run it on Windows 10, any more information needed?

Comment: What role is `npm` playing in your PHP project?

Comment: @DanielW: I found this setup on youtube(and also his repo), I thought it was very good and easy to use as base. However I was missing xdebug so tried to add it myself. However npm was also included and might be useful later, but currently I don´t use it. I tried to remove it but still no luck.
Here is the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I980aPL-NRM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this instructions [here](https://github.com/aschmelyun/docker-compose-laravel/pull/10/commits/c836d85b33302b49d5c4b540f40513316490756d) on how to set it up. Add it to the end of the php.dockerfile:

```
# Install base packages
RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade

# xdebug with VSCODE
ENV XDEBUG_VERSION=2.9.2
RUN apk --no-cache add --virtual .build-deps \
        g++ \
        autoconf \
        make && \
    pecl install xdebug-${XDEBUG_VERSION} && \
    docker-php-ext-enable xdebug && \
    apk del .build-deps && \
    rm -r /tmp/pear/* && \
    echo -e "xdebug.remote_enable=1\n\
        xdebug.remote_autostart=1\n\
        xdebug.remote_connect_back=0\n\
        xdebug.remote_port=9001\n\
        xdebug.idekey=\"VSCODE\"\n\
        xdebug.remote_log=/var/www/html/xdebug.log\n\
        xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini


# Change TimeZone
RUN apk add --update tzdata
ENV TZ=Europe/Bucharest
```

EDIT:
You should also remove the **xdebug port** in **docker-compose.yml** (In case you added it)

```
For **Visual Studio Code** Here is the kaunch.json I used:
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9001,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html/public": "${workspaceFolder}/src/public"
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Still not working. Everything starts but I can´t connect to the port. I tried:
```
> docker exec -it php sh
/var/www/html # netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:45201        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN      1/php-fpm.conf)
```
However I can see xdebug configured when using <?php phpinfo(); ?>. What is wrong?

Comment: What program are you using to connect phpstorm? What error do you get?

Comment: I use Visual code. This is the error I get:`Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::9001`

Comment: Ok, try to remove the xdebug port (9001) in compose.dockerfile. That should solve the issue.

Answer (score 10):

```
RUN apk add --no-cache $PHPIZE_DEPS \
    && pecl install xdebug-2.9.2 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug  \
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @NeoAnderson. Ι really can't come up with an explanation of a simple install command though. Fell free to update.

Comment: Thanks, but it complained about wrong version. What port should I use in this example?

Comment: Thank your for your answer Tania. While the reasoning behind your answer might be obvious for yourself, it might puzzle others. Perhaps that's why someone flagged and down-voted, which by the way, it's **NOT** a good reason to flag an answer. Code-snippets-only answers are ok, but having a brief explanation aside can only improve the quality of the answer. In this case, it is not very obvious why using `xdebug-2.7.0` instead of `2.9.2` as suggested in banankontakt's answer would make an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

All of current `stack` solutions use `pecl`. If you don't want to do it, follow current answer.

---

You can also use `docker-php-extension-installer` to install anything you want without knowing it's version like that:

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && \
    install-php-extensions gd xdebug

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
          libpng-dev \
          libonig-dev \
          libfreetype6-dev \
          libjpeg-dev \
          curl

RUN echo "zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug.so\n\n[xdebug]\nxdebug.mode=debug\nxdebug.start_with_request=yes\nxdebug.client_host=\"host.docker.internal\"\nxdebug.client_port=9000\nxdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log\nxdebug.remote_enable=1\nxdebug.remote_autostart=1\n" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini

RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-jpeg --with-freetype
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mysqli gd mbstring
RUN echo "date.timezone = Europe/Moscow" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```

That's all :_)